# Preventing inactive Chase bank accounts

Tags: banking, bank-account, online-banking

I had recently opened a Chase savings account and a checking account. I planned on using my checking account as a direct deposit. *Would automating transfers from checking to savings prevent my savings account becoming dormant?* I was wondering if this would be valid for checking to checking as well.

Comment: Ask Chase. The policy is almost certainly specific to your savings account type and institution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I have found that any transaction, besides an interest payment, will be enough to keep an account non-dormant.

In many cases activity in any related account is enough to keep all the related account non-dormant, but it might be possible that your bank doesn't extend this courtesy. You will have to ask.

If they require activity in the savings account, a small automatic transfer with each paycheck should more than meet the criteria for activity.